# Converting Large

Tags: java, android, image, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to devise a way for multiple high-quality images to be stored via Couchbase-Lite (Android) by converting them to Base64 Strings and storing them in a Couchbase document without completely running out of memory.

My current implementation cycles through a list of names ("image_file_names") for locally stored image files, decodes each in turn, captures the ByteArray representation, encodes to a Base64 string, and then inserts that value into an ArrayList.

The caveats here are that:
1) The image quality must be the highest available, and
2) The number of images is completely variable (0 or more without limit)

My current implementation is as follows:

```
ArrayList<byte[]> image_data_byte = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
ArrayList<String> image_data_string = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String image_file_name : image_file_names)
{
     String image_file_path = files_directory + File.separator + image_file_name;
     File image_file = new File(image_file_path);
     {
         ByteArrayOutputStream bitmap_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_file.getAbsolutePath());
         bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bitmap_stream);
         image_data_byte.add(bitmap_stream.toByteArray());
         String image_string = Base64.encodeToString(bitmap_stream.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
         image_data_string.add(image_string);
     }
}
```

So far, every piece of information I've found has been related either to displaying the images (via Async Task) or uploading the images via HTTP, but in my case I'm not attempting to display the images and all of the uploading is handled via Couchbase -- I'm trying to get to the point that I have the String representation before inserting the document into Couchbase.

The line that fails is specifically:

```
String image_string = Base64.encodeToString(bitmap_stream.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

With:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why would you want to store images in a database? you have them on file, store the file name

Answer (score 0):

With a quality of 100, in your code, you are exhausting memory for each image twice as large of its size, this will fail eventually as the number of images increase anyway.

Why keep duplicate information (one in a byte array and one in a string array)?
Anyhow, the best practice is to write this data in a sqlite database and retrieve it as required and do not keep a duplicate version. Conversion between a byte array and a string array using Base64 is quite fast.

This way, there will be no limit on the amount of images (well there is the devices storage limit)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Currently I have the images stored in the local vault, but then I need to get that the data of that image file into the Couchbase database so that it can be stored and synced to the remote server

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you only need the string or a blob representation of the Image to be stored in the database, so why not do that. I do not understand why you need to keep an array of "image_string"s. Just write each string in the database as you loop over the images. If you later need an "image_string" just retrieve it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [Couchbase Lite stores attachments](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/attachment/attachment/index.html).  You're probably best off attaching the image to JSON metadata.  This would, in effect, be like what @stopBugs mentions but with Couchbase instead of sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are not in a too expensive format (.bmp in general is inefficient), you can (at least for JPEG) load the images as **binary files**, not as image, and immediately encode it to a base64 string. This is faster and uses less memory / garbage collection.

Better would be to store the `byte[]` and  dynamically produce the Base64 String.

Even better would be to move the for-loop so a list is not needed, and the Base64 string is produced and written for every file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by moving the for loop? Thanks for the other tips -- you've given me some stuff to consider / work with

Comment: About an other control flow: that is for you to decide and fit in. Instead of collecting expensive data in a list, Maybe (just maybe) directly using it in a for-loop.